# How to remove warning about Unnecessary semicolon in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use the VS Code for my Python scripts, and I like to put a semicolon after every line, but the editor always emphasizes the semicolon and it distracts me a lot. 
Q: How do I disable this warning in the VS Code?

Comment: Maybe just train yourself not to use semicolons in your Python code, which are both unnecessary and unexpected? It will introduce an obstacle to sharing your code with others (or asking for help here).

Answer (score 0):

Huh, what an interesting habbit! I imagine updating a python linter in VS Code to ignore a semicolon is pretty easy: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting

There isn't an out-of-the-box solution that I know of.

Answer (score -1):

**Put a space after each semicolon.** You can also put a tab after it.

Comment: Kindly make some findings before the comment as it seems to be a lint config